# nodejs-polars: Error: not found: unable to find column

Tags: nodejs-polars

```js
"use strict";

const pl = require("nodejs-polars");
const fs = require("fs");

async function main() {
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./polars.csv");
  let df = await pl.readCSV(fileContent.toString());
  let filteredDf = df
    .filter(
      pl
        .col("Forecast indicator")
        .eq("Actual")
        .and(
          pl
            .col("Segment")
            .eq("Consumer")
            .and(pl.col("Month of Order Date").eq("February 2022"))
        )
    )
    .select(pl.col("Sales").apply((value) => value.replace("$", ""), "object"));

  console.log("filteredDf: ", filteredDf);
}

main();
```

I have this piece of code where the `Forecast indicator` is one of the column names of the csv. While the `df` (dataframe) gets generated properly, the `filteredDf` fails with the error: `Error: not found: unable to find column "Actual"`.

Can somebody please help?

"Forecast indicator", "Segment", "Sales" are the column names (csv headers) here
"Actual", "Consumer", "$2342342" etc are the values they hold respectively.

I am following the documentation (with all due respect not complaining but doesn't look very user friendly to me personally, ref: https://pola-rs.github.io/nodejs-polars/index.html), I am already lost in their documentation. At all the places, they have instructed to use the same approach of equating the column i.e `pl.col('Forecast indicator').eq('Actual')`.

Please let know if you need any more details from my end related to the code I am using! Happy to provide those.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you are missing `pl.lit` in `.eq(pl.lit("Actual"))`
Please create a MRE or a sample of `polars.csv`
Please reach out on Discord if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `pl.lit` in `.eq(pl.lit("Actual"))`